# Create Collection in CosmosDb via Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is there a way to create cosmosDb collections via Azure Templates or via Powershell?

All i have got so far are examples with the Azure CLI, but those do not fit my requirements.

I would also like to avoid Rest Calls, since this seams like a lot of overhead compared to the a possible Powershell solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the information provided [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/powershell-samples), you can only perform account related operations with PowerShell. It is not possible to manage data inside an account using PowerShell as of today.

> The following table includes links to sample Azure PowerShell scripts
>   for Azure Cosmos DB. At this time you can only manage the Azure Cosmos
>   DB accountlayer via PowerShell; **other resources such as databases and
>   collections cannot be managed via PowerShell**.

Also looking at the Azure Feedback site [`here`](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/13379637-manage-azure-documentdb-using-powershell), it is still unplanned but someone has started a project on Github for this. Do take a look at that project here: https://github.com/secabstraction/PoshDocs.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Cosmos DB PowerShell module available on the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/CosmosDB). You can find the documentation and examples of how to use it on [GitHub in the project repository](https://github.com/PlagueHO/CosmosDB#working-with-collections).

Answer (score 1):

You can try calling the REST API from powershell to achieve your goal [SEE REST API Dcumentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/create-a-collection)